# $T_4$-ness that is preserved by product

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

Sorgenfrey line demonstrates how normality can be not preserved when "squared."

Is there an example for a normal space $X$ for each of?:

- $X^2$ is normal, but $X^3$ is not
- $X^2$ and $X^3$ are normal, but $X^4$ is not
- $X^k$ is normal for $2 \leq k < n$, but $X^n$ is not
- $X^n$ is normal for $n \in \mathbb N$, but $X^\omega$ is not
- $X^n$ is normal for $n \in \mathbb N$, but $X^\omega$ is not, in box topology

Comment: Read Przymusinski's survey paper in the "Handbook of Set theoretic Topology" on products of normal spaces. This has all sorts of weaker results and generalisations etc.

Comment: The Michael line has the 4th property (See dantopology's blog for a proof). The others are all constructible (and Przymusinski was very active in that). The handbook I mentioned also has a chapter on box products with a whole subsection on normality there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first four questions, the answer is "yes", and I believe was first established in the paper

- *Przymusinski, Teodor C.*, [**Normality and paracompactness in finite and countable Cartesian products**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/fm-105-2-87-104), Fundam. Math. 105, 87-104 (1980). [ZBL0438.54021](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0438.54021).

Therein the following theorem is proved:

> **Theorem 1.1.**  For every $k$ and $m$ such that $1 \leq k \leq m \leq \omega$ there exists a separable and first-countable space $X = X ( k , m)$ such that
>
> 1. $X^n$ is paracompact (Lindelöf, subparacompact) if and only if $n < k$;
> 2. $X^n$ is normal (collectionwise normal) if and only if $n < m$.

The answer to the last question is also "yes", and an example was essentially established in

- *van Douwen, Eric K.*, [**Another nonnormal box product**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0016-660X(77)90009-5), General Topology Appl. 7, 71-76 (1977). [ZBL0341.54008](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0341.54008).

> **Theorem B.** $\Box^\omega ( 2^{\omega_2} )$ is not normal.

(I.e., the box product of $\omega$ copies of the Tychonoff product $2^{\omega_2} = \{ 0,1 \}^{\omega_2}$ is not normal.) Clearly $2^{\omega_2}$ is compact Hausdorff, hence normal, and each finite Tychonoff product $( 2^{\omega_2} )^n$ is homeomorphic to $2^{\omega_2}$.